# Taylor series expansion of $f(x)=\frac{sinx}{x-\pi}$ at $x=\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was solving it and on one step I need to find the 2nd Derivative of $f(x)$, I am getting -1/3, but according to book it's -1/6.Please help me out here.

Comment: do a transformation:  let $g(x) = -\frac{\sin x}{x}$.  Then it is easy to see that $f(x+\pi) = g(x)$, and the Taylor series expansion of $f$ about $x = \pi$ is equivalent to the Maclaurin series expansion of $g$ (about $x = 0$).  You will find the latter by taking the series for $\sin x$, negating it, and dividing each term by $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Taylor coefficient is $-\frac{1}{6}$, the derivative is $-\frac{1}{3}$. Remember that the Taylor coefficients are given by $$\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!},$$
not by $f^{(n)}(x_0)$.

The easiest method to obtain the Taylor series here is to write

$$\frac{\sin x}{x-\pi} = \frac{\sin (\pi+(x-\pi))}{x-\pi} = -\frac{\sin (x-\pi)}{x-\pi}.$$

Comment: Thanks ,In book derivative and coefficient were written ambiguously ,got confused.